# Android - Can I edit a file in \Android\data\com.zzzzzz.zzz?

Tags: android, file

I have a Xiaomi device, not rooted.

I have an app and I want to try to see where it saves its data, I think it's in \Android\data\com.zzzzz.zzz (app name).

When I go that folder from my Windows PC I can see there are 2 subfolders but each of them appears to be empty.
Is it possible that the the subfolders are not empty and that I see them empty because the phone is not rooted?

If I connect to the phone with adb shell, is there a way to see if the subfolders are actually empty?

Thank you very much.

Comment: No you should see the files if there are any. You can just test this with your own app.

Answer (score 1):

This is the command to get files from device `adb pull Android\data\data\com.zzzzz.zzz`.
You can list all files in the folder by `$ adb exec-out run-as com.yourcompany.app ls -R /data/data/com.yourcompany.app/`
Or you can use android studio device file explorer from sidebar to see your files.

Comment: Thank you for your input. After I send the adb pull command, I have this:
/system/bin/sh: adb: inaccessible or not found

Answer (score 1):

You can't see the files if the app is not debuggable